# XSLT If nested node attributes values are less than 800

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this XML

```
    <ContentBlock>
    <Content>
        <QuickStatus Balance="0" Credits="0" Trolley="600" Delivery="100" Available="-700" Pending="0" />
        <TrolleyItems>
            <TrolleyItem Description="Test Item 1" value="150" />
            <TrolleyItem Description="Test Item 2" value="150" />
            <TrolleyItem Description="Test Item 3" value="300" />
        </TrolleyItems>
    </Content>
</ContentBlock>
```

I need to check if each of the trolly items value attributes are under 800 and then show the Final delivery attribute if at least one of the items are under 800. But only need to show the Delivery value once.

My XSLT .xsl file code looks like this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem">
    <xsl:if test="ContentBlock/Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem/@value &lt; 800">
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;">
            <xsl:for-each select="Content/Final">
            <td>Delivery Fee</td><td><xsl:value-of select="@Delivery"/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

What I need is to output one item for the @Delivery attribute.

It will only show one time for example the answer will be: "Delivery Costs: 100". So Delivery is only charged when the item value is less than 800

![enter image description here][1]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show the output that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `xsl:if` and `xsl:for-each` shouldn't have the full path.

All nodes within the `xsl:for-each` are relative to the xpath in the `select`, and because you're using relative paths (they don't start with `/` or `//`) then you're looking for

```
Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem/ContentBlock/Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem
```

What I think you're looking for is something like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem[@value">
  <xsl:if test="./@value &lt; 800">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;">
      <xsl:for-each select="/Content/Final">
        <td>Delivery Fee</td><td><xsl:value-of select="@Delivery"/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See [this xmlplayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/1ZvILh) for a live demo

**Update**

Even more efficient...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem[@value &lt; 800]">
  <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Content/Final">
      <td>Delivery Fee</td><td><xsl:value-of select="@Delivery"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Update**

Based on the comment by the OP, maybe something more like this (bearing in mind that I assume your actual XML will be a lot more complex that you're currently showing, so this is probably not exactly what you're looking for)...

```
<xsl:if test="Content/TrolleyItems/TrolleyItem/@value &lt; 800">
  <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;">
    <td>Delivery Fee</td><td><xsl:value-of select="/Content/Final/@Delivery"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi Freefaller thanks for this, is there a way to limit the output to only show one output for the @Delivery at the moment it shows 3 times.

Comment: @Morne, I assumed you wanted multiple rows, as that's why you'd put the `for-each`.  Can you **edit** your question with exactly what you'd expect to get out for the input XML?  A couple of examples would be good

Comment: I've changed my question a bit with more info and screenshot

Comment: Great it works. I just had to do the select part like this: select="//Final/@Delivery" and that showed the value.

Comment: @Morne, glad to be of service... good luck completing your project :-)